# How to unhide property hidden in the base model in loopbackjs?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to make **password** property of User model to be visible in Loopback explorer, in such case it should not be hidden. Is it possible to revert visibility of the property hidden in the base model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete `password` from hidden properties of the `User`.

You can create a boot script and put below code there :

```
var filtered = app.models.User.settings.hidden.filter(function(item)
{
 return item !== 'password';
}
);
app.models.User.settings.hidden = filtered;
```